# $5$ boys and $3$ girls seated in a round table, find no. of ways so that no $2$ girls are together.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

When $5$ boys and $3$ girls are seated around the table so that no girls are adjacent.

I know the number of ways is $1440$, as $5$ boys can be seated around the table using $4!$ ways and there are $5$ spaces between them so girls can be seated in $5\cdot4\cdot3$ ways

so total number of ways $4! \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3  = 1440$

However, when I try to solve the problem using the complementary principle, I do not get the same answer. can you provide the answer with an explanation with a complementary principle?

Comment: It would help if you showed your work.  Presumably, you overcounted (assigning $2$ girls as adjacent and then letting the other girl be assigned freely), but without seeing your work, that's just a guess. 
 In any case, to count the patterns with at least $2$ adjacent girls you need to split into cases:  exactly $2$ and exactly $3$.  Both cases are straightforward (though the direct method is preferable).

Comment: total ways 7!
when all 3 girls are seated together = 5! * 3!
when 2 girls are togeher = 5! * 2! * 4, 4 is the no. of choices for 1 girl which is not counted

i am getting 3360, what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please edit your post to show your work, don't leave it for the comments.  Also, are you assuming that rotated arrangements are the same?  If so, you should say that.

Comment: In any case:  assuming rotations don't matter, there are $7!$ unrestricted arrangements.  If exactly $2$ girls are together, then we pick the two girls in order ($6$ ways to do that), pick a slot for the two girls ($5$ ways), pick a slot of the lone girl ($4$ ways) so $4!\times 6\times 5\times 4$, which is not what you wrote.